# -Like, -Match in subarray

Tags: powershell, active-directory, operators, contains, group-membership

I am working on getting a list of inactive users from Active Directory with `Search-ADAccount` then piping that to `Get-ADUser` so I can use where `MemberOf` does not contain the group `"Accounts_to_Keep"`. I believe I have it working with the correct number (`379`) with the full DN string. In case the group moves, though, I would like to use `-match` or `-like` to just use the name of the group. The number it returns is not the same.

If I do this individually on a single user with `MemberOf` it just filters out the one group and returns the other the user has so I think this is why I have more than the `-contains`. Is there a way to use `-like` or `-match` for the subarray without `foreach`ing it myself?

Full DN removed from string

```bsh
PS> $InactiveAll.Count
488
PS> ($InactiveAll | Where {-not $_.memberof.contains("CN=Accounts_to_Keep,OU=DC")}).Count 
379
PS> ($InactiveAll | Where { $_.memberof -notlike "*Accounts_To_keep*"}).Count 
427
PS> ($InactiveAll | Where {-not $_.memberof -contains ("CN=Accounts_to_Keep,OU=DC")}).Count 
61
PS> ($InactiveAll | Where {-not ($_.memberof -contains ("CN=Accounts_to_Keep,OU=DC"))}).Count
379
PS> ($InactiveAll | Where { $_.memberof -notmatch "Accounts_To_Keep"}).Count
427
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-like and -notlike use wildcards, `"*"`.  Also using -notlike and -notmatch on an array of groups have a different result than using them on single elements.  I think you need to research what these operators do.  Any result will evaluate to "true" in where-object.

```
'group1','group2','group3' -notmatch 'group1'
group2
group3


'group1','group2','group3' -notlike '*group1*'
group2
group3
```

Here's a way to search for substrings in an array of strings:

```
| where { -not ($_.memberof | select-string group1) }
```

Or

```
| where { -not ($_.memberof -match 'group1') }
| where { -not ($_.memberof -like '*group1*') }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `-match` would offer any advantage over `-like` for testing distinguished names since, in this case, you know `'CN=Accounts_to_Keep'` will identify the desired group by name.  Don't forget that `-notcontains` exists to simplify your code a little bit.

This code might be a little off since I don't have a directory in front me to test against, but if you want to exclude members of that group wherever it may exist I think you should *let Active Directory handle finding the group*...

```bsh
$groupToExclude = Get-ADGroup -Identity 'Accounts_to_Keep'
```

...and then instead of matching distinguished name substrings you can match the distinguished name as a whole...

```bsh
($InactiveAll | Where { $_.MemberOf -notcontains $groupToExclude.DistinguishedName}).Count
```

This assumes there is only one group in the domain named `Accounts_to_Keep`.  If that cannot be guaranteed, instead of its name you could pass that group's `objectGUID` or `objectSid` to `Get-ADGroup` to retrieve that exact group with no ambiguity.

Comment: That's a good point on grabbing the group from AD first I just didn't want it hard coded. This fixes both issues. Thank you.